# mat autocomplete - how to set option not found

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-autocomplete

How to set option not found for mat mat-autocomplete.

Below is my code:

```html
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of items | async" [value]="item">
{{item.value}}
</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

The equivalent element in AngularJS is

```html
<md-autocomplete ...>
   <md-item-template>
      ...
   </md-item-template>
   <md-not-found>
      No item matching "{{myText}}" were found.
   </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
```

What is the AngularJS md-not-found equivalent in mat-autocomplete

Answer (score 2):

There's no such option at the moment in material design for Angular according to the [autocomplete.ts source code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/63be232283262615fa2130900c80dd570eff6cda/src/lib/autocomplete/autocomplete.ts), there's also a [Github Issue #13013 "No implementation of md-not-found for Autocomplete in Angular2+"](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13013) with a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I used *disabled* on the mat-option and mapped an empty result when the actual results were empty.

```
 <mat-option *ngFor="let result of results | async" [disabled]="result.id === 0" ...

 this.results = this.searchControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    filter(s => s !== ''),
    debounceTime(700),
    mergeMap(s=> this._getSearchFunction(s)),
    map(data => {
      if (data.length === 0) {
        data = [{ id: 0, displayName: 'No Results' }];
      }
      return data;
    })
  );
```

Comment: Works perfect in angular 14, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

as a work around I've added a custom validator which accepts drop down list as array and the selected value to check if the value exists.